# How to avoid MS Access error: the command or action Paste is not available now

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have just upgraded from MS Access 2013 to 2019 and my duplicate record buttons have stopped working. I get the error "The command or action Paste is not available now". Have looked through the Trust Center for anything that might be upsetting it but I cannot see anything. I created a new button using the Duplicate Record wizard, and that has the same problem. So it's not my code.

```
Private Sub Command115_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command115_Click


    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPaste

Exit_Command115_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command115_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command115_Click
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of hairpulling. I have arrived at a work around. Just putting a pause of point one second before the paste avoids the error message. So it seems there is some kind of timing issue. Might be some kind of record locking problem that only occurs on slower computers.

```
    Private Sub Copy_Record_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Copy_Record_Click


    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
        Pause (0.1)
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPaste

Exit_Copy_Record_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Copy_Record_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Copy_Record_Click
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

We recently experienced this with the Duplicate Record button macro. The solution was to turn off the clipboard history at: Settings > System > Clipboard. Locate the option titled “Clipboard history” and toggle the switch to “Off.” This allowed the paste to occur. When I toggled history back on, the paste failed again. The clipboard history is what you see when you open the clipboard using Windows+V.

Comment: Interesting, but a bit of a pain to have to do that every time.